# Using JFrame and JFileChooser to select a File

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am attempting to integrate `JFileChooser` into my program. Essentially, I would like to have a interface to select a CSV file to be read into my program. I'm trying to do this using `JFileChooser`. Examples I've seen elsewhere show this being done, but the `JFileChooser` opens up right away without the `JFrame`. Is there a way to have `JFileChooser` be a child element of my `JFrame` element?

My code is below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class QuitButtonExample extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public QuitButtonExample() {
        initUI();
        quitButton();
        menu();
        fileChooser();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(
            "Selct the .csv file contaning the addresses to be geocoded...");
        label1.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 50);
        panel.add(label1); 
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize(1000, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void quitButton() {

        // Quit Button

        panel.setLayout(null);
        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.setBounds(0, 50, 80, 30);

        quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(quitButton);
        setTitle("Quit Button");
    }

    private void menu() {
        // Menu Bar

        // "File"
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit"); // eMenuItem
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        file.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(file);

        // "Credits"
        JMenu credits = new JMenu("Credits");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About...");
        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0); // TODO - New window, showing credits for
                        // project
            }
        });

        credits.add(about);
        menuBar.add(credits);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    private void fileChooser() {
        // FileChooser

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "CSV Files", "csv");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setBounds(0, 75, 500, 300);
        panel.add(chooser);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        QuitButtonExample ex = new QuitButtonExample();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call  `fileChooser()` in side the constructor. change that one and call  `fileChooser()` inside a `ActionListener`  ie whether a `button` is clicked or `Menuitem` is pressed. So after corresponding action `JFilechooser` will come in the action.

**Edit**:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fileChooserAddDoc.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add functionality to the "Open" and "Save" buttons in the JFileChooser dialog? If so, how? Just adding an actionListener to them?

Comment: *YES* fileChooser.showSaveDialog(); for save and fileChooser.showOpenDialog(); for open

Answer (score 0):

Start by not calling `QuitButtonExample` within the constructor.

Instead, create a menu open called `Open` (for example) and within it's `ActionListener` call the method instead

Take a look at [How to use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code works as it should.

You are adding a JFileChooser (which is a JComponent) to a JFrame's panel. Like any other JComponent, the file chooser is nested within the frame. What you are seeing is the frame (evident from the menus) with the file chooser being one of its components.